# Do we need to think of moderator elections for Main and Meta once site goes Live?

Tags: discussion, election

Sometime back, on stackOverflow moderator elections are started.

Immediately I thought of Tridion moderator elections, whether it's the right time to think of moderator elections for Main and Meta sites, once sites goes Live?

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to start a "nominate moderators" post. Feel free to post the question in this meta. :-) Or maybe solicit some rules/guidelines in this or another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post by Robert Caraino: [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) from 2010 is linked to by ['The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) and seems to address just this issue.

From reading the post, it sounds like shortly after our SE site goes into public beta, SE's Community Development team will identify people they think will do a good job of being moderators and will try to find 3 of those people who are willing to be temporary moderators while the site is in beta.

> About a week into the public beta, we will **seek out members who are
>   deeply engaged in the community’s development**; members who:
>
> - Have a
>     reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent
>     participation.
> - Show an interest in their meta’s community-building
>     activities.
> - Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their
>     fellow community members in everything they write.
> - Exhibit those
>     intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

It further sounds like SE welcomes and encourages the community's input in this process via nominating process:

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start
>   one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the
>   site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our
>   choice.